# Counting words and characters in Bash without wc

Tags: bash

I have a variable set like this:

```
sentence="a very long sentence with multiple       spaces"
```

I need to count how many words and characters are there without using other programs such as wc.

I know counting words can be done like this:

```
words=( $sentence )
echo ${#words[@]}
```

But how do I count the characters including spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how do I count the characters including spaces?

To count length of string use:

```
echo "${#sentence}"
47
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` on a single line:

```
echo this string | awk '{print length}'
```

Another way of piping stdin text to `awk`:

```
awk '{print length}' <<< "this string"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `grep` with a regex that matches everything:

```
echo "this string" | grep -oP . | grep -c .
```